# Reverse framework7 page transition

Tags: reactjs, html-framework-7

I am using **framework7** & **React**. In a `Page` I have left & right nav bar buttons.

- Now when I click on the right button (a normal link that takes to the specified route) the page transitions form right to left as normally expected.
- But somehow I am unable to get the **reverse transition** for the other page.

How do I have a page transition from left/backward/reverse?

What I tried:

- Added the setting `page.direction = "backward"` as specified in the docs. I added that in `onPageInit` of the specific page.

I wonder whether I am doing routing right, because all I am doing right now is using standard links (`<a href="...">`) for going to another page.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct API as far as I understand and I solved it using a hack.

To have a page transition backward, use the following:

```
router.back(url, {force: true})
```

The option with `force` key is important to force the router to navigate to the specified `url` than going to the previous url from history.